# Function as a parameter of a function

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have 2 functions:

Checkboxes creator:

```
function AddCheckBoxes($title,$box_values,$box_titles){
    echo '<div class="form-group"><label>' . $title . '</label>';
    $boxes_values_titles = new MultipleIterator();
    $boxes_values_titles->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($box_values));
    $boxes_values_titles->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($box_titles));
    foreach ( $boxes_values_titles as $value ) {
        list($box_values, $box_titles) = $value;
        echo '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="' . $box_values . '">' . $box_titles , '</label></div>' , PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Panel with tabs creator:

```
function AddBasicTabsPanel($tabs_ids,$tabs_names,$tabs_data){
    //START TABS HEADERS
    echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">';
    //PRINT TABS HEADERS
    $tabs_ids_names_data = new MultipleIterator();
    $tabs_ids_names_data->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($tabs_ids));
    $tabs_ids_names_data->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($tabs_names));
    $tabs_ids_names_data->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($tabs_data));
    foreach ( $tabs_ids_names_data as $ids_names_data ) {
        list($tabs_ids, $tabs_names, $tabs_data) = $ids_names_data;
        echo '<li><a href="#' . $tabs_ids . '" data-toggle="tab">' . $tabs_names . '</a></li>' , PHP_EOL;
    }
    //END TABS HEADERS
    echo '</ul>';
    //START TAB PANES
    echo '<div class="tab-content">';
    //PRINT TAB PANES
    foreach ( $tabs_ids_names_data as $ids_names_data ) {
        list($tabs_ids, $tabs_names, $tabs_data) = $ids_names_data;
        echo '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' . $tabs_ids . '"><h4>' . $tabs_names . '</h4>' . $tabs_data . '</div>' , PHP_EOL;
    }
    //END TAB PANES
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Currently, when I try the following code:

```
AddBasicTabsPanel(["One","Two","Three"],["One","Two","Three"],["data","Some data","More data"]);
```

I get a proper tabs element with all the data displayed. Picture:

[image]

But when I want to replace the text in the tabs_data with checkboxes function, the checkboxes are displayed before the panel with tabs.

```
AddBasicTabsPanel(["One","Two","Three"],["One","Two","Three"],[AddCheckBoxes("Checkboxes",["20","39","31"],["One","Two","Three"]),"Some data","More data"]);
```

Picture:

[image]

I tried troubleshooting this for hours, but no clue how to use checkboxes function as a parameter of a function for panel with tabs creation. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Biffen thanks for editing the code!

Comment: Because `AddCheckBoxes` __outputs__ html for checkboxes. And for your case it should __return__ this html as a string which will be passed as argument to `AddBasicTabsPanel()`.

Comment: I tried putting "return" instead of "echo" in the foreach function after "//PRINT TAB PANES", but no result was shown. Maybe I'm putting "return" in the wrong place? I'm still a beginner in PHP :)

Comment: `AddCheckBoxes` should return values, not `AddBasicTabsPanel`.

Comment: How can I achieve that AddCheckBoxes returns html as string?

Comment: `return "Your string here";`

Comment: And the code fails if I try replacing any of the "echo" with "return".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing checkboxes before because that's the order in which functions are being executed. The problem you're having is AddCheckBoxes is called before AddBasicTabsPanel and it prints out things and returns null. Meaning your code is

1. printing out AddCheckBoxes
2. calling `AddBasicTabsPanel(["One","Two","Three"],["One","Two","Three"],[null,"Some data","More data"]);`

You can return string from your method doing something like this.

```
function AddCheckBoxes($title,$box_values,$box_titles) {
    $result = '';
    $result+= '<div class="form-group"><label>' . $title . '</label>';
    $boxes_values_titles = new MultipleIterator();
    $boxes_values_titles->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($box_values));
    $boxes_values_titles->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($box_titles));
    foreach ( $boxes_values_titles as $value ) {
        list($box_values, $box_titles) = $value;
        $result+= '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="' . $box_values . '">' . $box_titles . '</label></div>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Also your snippet has `,` instead of `.` in few places.

Wouldn't it make more sense if you have each argument representing individual tab and it's data? Instead of having 3 arguments having data for 3 tabs, you can have something like this

```
$tab1 = [
    'id' => 'tab1-id',
    'name' => 'tab1-name',
    'data' => 'tab1-data',
];

$tab2 =  [
    'id' => 'tab2-id',
    'name' => 'tab2-name',
    'data' => YourMethodThatReturnsWhateverHTMLYouWant(),
];

AddBasicTabsPanel($tab1, $tab2);
```

Also you don't need `MultipleIterator()`

```
function AddCheckBoxes($title, $checkboxes) {
    $result = '<div class="form-group"><label>' . $title . '</label>';

    foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox) {
        $result+= '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="' . $checkbox['value'] . '">' . $checkbox['title] . '</label></div>' . PHP_EOL;  
    }

    return $result;
}

$checkboxes = [
    [
        'title' => 'checkbox1-title',
        'value' => 20,
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'checkbox2-title',
        'value' => 39,
    ],
];

$checkboxHtml = AddCheckBoxes('Checkbox-title', $checkboxes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried, but couldn't get your first code to work. thank you for the reminder that each argument can represent one tab, as it makes way clearer to read and code. I use multipleiterator because of the code tidyness, as I work in a group and it makes it easier to read (there is not a lot of PHP code so it doesn't slow the page loading too much)